# Parsing date from string using dateutil parser

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am trying to parse date which have string format as

> u'June 11, 2015 - 12:26 hrs IST'

but when I am using dateutil parser to parse I am getting error.

```
 from dateutil.parser import parse
 parse("u'June 11, 2015 - 12:26 hrs IST'")
```

Here is the error traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rranjan/.virtualenvs/crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 982, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rranjan/.virtualenvs/crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 390, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Comment: why are you putting `u'` inside another string? Where does that come from?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I am extracting date from a webpage. I even tried  converting it to string but it doesn't helped me.

Comment: Its solved, the problem was "hrs" string.

Comment: Please mark your question as solved.

Comment: @Rahul you can answer your own quesiton and accept that answer. It would also help others who may get siimlar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experimenting with different formats and finally, when I removed `hrs` from the date string, it worked.

```
 from dateutil.parser import parse
 parse("June 11, 2015 - 12:26 IST")

 // this gives
 datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 11, 12, 26, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

To learn more what `dateutil` formatting requirement is, follow this [link](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo).